# No line of regression appear when I use regplot and lmplot for seaborn using imported CSV data

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, linear-regression, scatter-plot

I want to create a linear regression model for the rent over a number of years in Tokyo. So far, I have managed to do the scatter plot with seaborn. However, when I try to do linear regression, the error UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32') pops up and there is no line of regression (but the scatter plot seems to work fine).

My code

```
df = pd.read_csv('Tokyo rent (One Bedroom apartment in the city centre).csv', thousands=',')
g = sns.lmplot(x='Date 2.0', y='Rent(Local Currency)', data=df)
g.figure.autofmt_xdate()
```

My CSV File

```
Year    Rent(USD)   Date    Rent(Local Currency)    Date 2.0
2017    1223.4  17/03/17    129,594.59              2017-03-17
2017    1070.24 28/10/17    121,656.25              2017-10-28
2018    1104.51 23/01/18    121,689.66              2018-01-23
2018    1030.61 22/10/18    116,270.83              2018-10-22
2019    1124.33 14/06/19    122,062.50              2019-06-14
2019    1129.6  20/06/19    121,255.32              2019-06-20
2019    1129.9  21/06/19    121,255.32              2019-06-21
2020    1198.53 23/03/20    128,701.75              2020-03-23
2020    1183.66 01/07/20    127,195.65              2020-07-01
2020    1213.38 17/09/20    127,466.67              2020-09-17
2020    1168.37 05/10/20    123,578.95              2020-10-05
2020    1192.5  11/11/20    125,525.00              2020-11-11
2020    1228.34 02/12/20    128,312.50              2020-12-02
2021    1220    06/03/21    132,200.00              2021-03-06
2021    1342.84 29/08/21    147,524.40              2021-08-29
2021    1284.65 14/10/21    145,696.54              2021-10-14
```

My scatter plot result (sorry for the crushed dates)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the x-axis is a time series, so once we convert it to matplotlib's date numeric format, we can display the regression line. You can then change the x-axis display to a time series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

data = '''
Year    Rent(USD)   Date    "Rent(Local Currency)"    "Date 2.0"
2017    1223.4  17/03/17    129,594.59              2017-03-17
2017    1070.24 28/10/17    121,656.25              2017-10-28
2018    1104.51 23/01/18    121,689.66              2018-01-23
2018    1030.61 22/10/18    116,270.83              2018-10-22
2019    1124.33 14/06/19    122,062.50              2019-06-14
2019    1129.6  20/06/19    121,255.32              2019-06-20
2019    1129.9  21/06/19    121,255.32              2019-06-21
2020    1198.53 23/03/20    128,701.75              2020-03-23
2020    1183.66 01/07/20    127,195.65              2020-07-01
2020    1213.38 17/09/20    127,466.67              2020-09-17
2020    1168.37 05/10/20    123,578.95              2020-10-05
2020    1192.5  11/11/20    125,525.00              2020-11-11
2020    1228.34 02/12/20    128,312.50              2020-12-02
2021    1220    06/03/21    132,200.00              2021-03-06
2021    1342.84 29/08/21    147,524.40              2021-08-29
2021    1284.65 14/10/21    145,696.54              2021-10-14
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True, thousands=',')

df['Date 2.0'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date 2.0'])
df['Date 2.0'] = mdates.date2num(df['Date 2.0'])

import seaborn as sns

g = sns.lmplot(x='Date 2.0', y='Rent(Local Currency)', data=df)

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)

g.ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
g.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

[image]

Comment: That is awesome! It works! But I am not sure how 4 the lines of code works below 'g = sns.lmplot(x='Date 2.0', y='Rent(Local Currency)', data=df)' means (this is the locator stuff and how do they create the regression model.

Comment: If you disable these four lines, you can see the reality of the situation: these are the four lines that automatically optimize matplotlib's time series format. See this for [more details](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html).

Comment: Ahh I see. When I remove the the 4 lines, it changes the x axes. But when re-enter the 4 lines in the graph, the whole graph gets messed up (the x axes and the actual scatter plot becomes one vertical line).

Comment: I don't know what your runtime environment is, but have you rerun it including the following? `df['Date 2.0'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date 2.0']);df['Date 2.0'] = mdates.date2num(df['Date 2.0'])`

Comment: Yeah, mine is Jupyter Notebook. I did include that. I just a bit of tinkering and I figure out every time I run the code (df['Date 2.0'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date 2.0']);df['Date 2.0'] = mdates.date2num(df['Date 2.0'])) these two lines affect the x axis (maybe every time you run it always tries to convert if further which messes it up a bit).  I think these two lines are the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have updated the entire code that I created based on the data you presented. Please check it with this whole code. My runtime environment is jupyterLab 3.2.0.

Comment: Ahh yeah, the problem is solved. But I'd rather assign the data as a link (like data = 'Tokyo rent (One Bedroom apartment in the city centre).csv') instead of just copying and pasting the csv file (i did try that but it didn't work out)

Comment: I don't intentionally create and load CSV files, but directly copy-paste the data as CSV. So if you read the file with `read_csv` in the question, you will get the same result.

Comment: Yeah when I do data = pd.read_csv('Tokyo rent (One Bedroom apartment in the city centre).csv', thousands=','), it doesn't seem to work because the StringIO(data) doesn't accept dataframes. But thanks for helping out, it has been very useful :).

Comment: This and this are the same. `df = pd.read_csv('Tokyo rent (One Bedroom apartment in the city centre).csv', thousands=',')` `df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True, thousands=',')`

Comment: Awesome! That's solves everything. Thank you so much!